# htacces redirect to one specific page depending on .tld AND excluding a specific folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I can't find the solution to this problem:

I'd like to redirect domain.com and all subdirectories and documents to one specific page: special_info.html

But I want ONLY domain.com to be redirected (NOT domain.de)
AND I want to exclude a specific folder from redirection.

Examples:

domain.com should be redirected to domain.com/special_info.html

domain.de/anything should not be redirected

domain.com/any_directory/any_page.html should be redirected to domain.com/special_info.html as well

but

domain.com/shop should NOT be redirected

Any help is appreciated, Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^(shop/|special_info\.html) /special_info.html [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: .. is was not exactly what I was looking for because existing directories are not redirected – but a great help for me anyway. Thanks again!!
if it can be improoved: I looked for redirection of all pages and subdirectories to a special page except for pages of one special directory, in my case /shop

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible by using domain management console , like godaddy's.( I have done it earlier)

Following link may help for your problem , if you have your domain with godaddy.

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/422/forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name

Did you try from following,

http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/